# Insert a 0 infront of values with incomplete start_time and end_time

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a data set where there is a start_time column and an end_time column for each survey conducted. There is some errors in the data where a leading zero was not included for the end_time (ex: 1:25, correct: 01:25)

| start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- |
| 12:45 | 14:32 |
| 02:34 | 02:58 |
| 06:34 | 8:23 |

How do I add a leading zero to the columns with incomplete times? The columns are in character formate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R:

```
data.frame(gsub("\\b(\\d{1})\\b", "0\\1", as.matrix(df)))

  start_time end_time
1      12:45    14:32
2      02:34    02:58
3      06:34    08:23
```

Comment: that works, thank you. Could you please explain the logic behind it?

Comment: @Jake this uses regular expression to capture digits that are by themselves. replace those digits by addid a 0 in front of them